# executing startWeblogic.sh and startNodemanager.sh in the same script

Tags: weblogic

I need to write a single shell script in which I need to execute both `startWebLogic.sh` and `startNodeManager.sh`. `startWebLogic.sh` is getting executed but `startnodeMananger.sh` is not when put into the same script. This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /u01/middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/bin 
startWebLogic.sh
startNodeManager.sh
```

What change should I bring in my script?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about what you are trying to accomplish, it looks
like your "start" shell scripts never return (perhaps they start a
service, but leave it in the foreground). If so, you may be looking
for this instead, which will run the two scripts in the background:

```
startWebLogic.sh &
startNodeManager.sh &
```

Note, however, that with the ampersands added, your script will
complete immediately after starting the two "start" shell scripts. You
may want to use a proper service manager if you need more precise
control.